# POST JSON Object via RestTemplate causes Response 400 BAD_REQUEST

Tags: java, json, spring, post, resttemplate

I'm trying to send POST request with JSON data to some Swagger API, but it causes error:
`{"error":{"message":"Invalid json message received","status":400}}`

Here is the code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
messageConverters.add(converter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

String date = "05/13/2019";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("startDate", date);
jsonObject.put("endDate", date);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(),headers);

String url = "https://api/reports/";

ResponseEntity<List> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,entity,List.class);
```

Spring log:

```
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate : HTTP POST https://api/reports/
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate : Accept=[application/json]
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate : Writing [{"endDate":"05/13/2019","startDate":"05/13/2019"}] as "application/json"
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate : Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
c.s.my.controller.ApiClient : Error.Body: {"error":{"message":"Invalid json message received","status":400}}
c.s.my.controller.ApiClient : Error.Headers: [Date:"Fri, 17 May 2019 07:18:03 GMT", Content-Type:"application/json", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Connection:"keep-alive", Server:"nginx", X-Powered-By:"PHP/5.6.32", Cache-Control:"no-cache"]
```

But when i'm sending request via curl:

```
curl -X POST "https://api/reports/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"endDate\":\"05/13/2019\",\"startDate\":\"05/13/2019\"}"
```

It works fine!

When i'm trying to send JSONObject like:

```
HttpEntity<JSONObject> entity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject,headers);
```

There is another error: `Response 422 UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY` with response body:

```
{"errors":{"list":{"report_campaign_single_form":["This form should not contain extra fields.: empty"],"startDate":["This value should not be blank."],"endDate":["This value should not be blank."]},"status":422}}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: what does your swagger api recieve?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I don't know, because it's remote API

Comment: you do not know what the api you are calling expects? you should be able to see this through swagger

Comment: @AmerQarabsa API expects only 2 String parameters: startDate and endDate http://prntscr.com/nppk21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting request with CharlesProxy I found answer!

When I pass `jsonObject` as a `String`:

```
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(),headers);
```

Request looks like:

```
"{\"endDate\":\"05/13/2019\",\"startDate\":\"05/13/2019\"}"
```

As we can see it's not correct JSON data, then I pass `jsonObject` as `Map`:

```
HttpEntity<Map> entity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toMap(),headers);
```

and it works perfect:

```
{
    "endDate": "05/13/2019",
    "startDate": "05/13/2019"
}
```

Brings me 200 OK response